# Javascript - React wraps my component in a div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components

So I have two similar components, they have different structures but share the same CSS classes, but one of them gets wrapped in a div by React for no reason.

Both components are used in lists on the same view, but since one of them gets wrapped in a div, the width of that one gets weird.

Any reason why react is wrapping the component in an extra div?

This is the component that gets wrapped:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Card, CardBlock, CardFooter, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button, Input     } from 'reactstrap'

class ActiveInvoice extends Component {

  check(selected) {    
    if(!selected){
      this.props.cart.Add({id: this.props.id, amount: this.props.amount}) 
    } 
    else {
      this.props.cart.Remove({id: this.props.id, amount: this.props.amount})     
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { receiver, dueDate, amount, currency, status, id } = this.props
    const selected = this.props.cartReducer.selectedInvoices.find((x) => x     === id) ? true : false
    return (
      <Card className='invoice'>
        <CardBlock onClick={() => this.check(selected)} className={selected ?     'checked' : 'unchecked'}>
          <Input className='selector' type='checkbox' checked={selected}     readOnly/>
          <CardTitle>{receiver}</CardTitle>
          <CardSubtitle className='due'>Förfallodatum {dueDate}    </CardSubtitle>
          <CardSubtitle className='status'>{status}</CardSubtitle>
          <CardTitle className='amount'>{amount} <span className='currency'>    {currency}</span></CardTitle>
        </CardBlock>
        <CardFooter>
          <Button className='pay'>Betala</Button>
          <Button className='details'>Detaljer</Button>
        </CardFooter>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}

export default ActiveInvoice
```

This one doesn't get wrapped:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Card, CardBlock, CardFooter, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, CardText,     Button } from 'reactstrap'

class InactiveInvoice extends Component {

  render() {
    const { receiver, amount, currency, status, description } = this.props
    return (
      <Card className='invoice inactive'>
        <CardBlock>
          <CardTitle>{receiver}</CardTitle>
          <CardSubtitle className='status teal'>{status}</CardSubtitle>
          <CardTitle className='amount'>{amount} <span className='currency'>    {currency}</span></CardTitle>
          <CardText>{description}</CardText>
        </CardBlock>
        <CardFooter>
          <Button className='details'>Detaljer</Button>
        </CardFooter>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}

export default InactiveInvoice
```

[image: React Code where the components are used in view]

React Code, where the components are used in view

[image: Components next to each other, one is narrow because it's wrapped]

Code in inspector where one of the components is wrapped

[image: Code in inspector where one of the components is wrapped]

Components next to each other, one is narrow because it's wrapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. A container was created for the component that got wrapped which wrapped it in a div.